# Change <head></head> in DotNetNuke without Host Access

Tags: content-management-system, dotnetnuke

I need to make a change to the header of a DotNetNuke website I have Admin access but not host access. I can also access the file directory of the website via FTP.

Is it possible for me to make changes to the header of the index page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are talking about making changes within the

```
<head></head>
```

section of the document, you can set this up on a page-by-page basis in the page settings.  From a global basis there isn't really a way to do it, unless you want to modify default.aspx directly in the core.

Comment: I don't see any option for changing any page's code. All I can access is the code of 'modules'. The header is the same on every page so the code must be in some central location.

Comment: The actual header is defined in default.aspx as part of the core. If you select "Settings" on a specific page you can add additional header tags.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on the changes you wish to make to your header.  In any case though, you would need additional functionality added by someone else.  For example, if you simply want to inject content into the header, you can use an [injection module](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Extensions-Forge/view/ProjectDetail/project/wnsinj.aspx) to inject anything you want into the page header.  Or, you can do this through a skin.  Unfortunately, like Mitchel said, without some configuration you are limited in available options.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to determine where the content is coming from.  If it's in the skin, then you'll need to edit the skin files via FTP (probably in /Portals/_default/Skins or /Portals/[Portal ID]/Skins).

If it's just a module in a header pane, then you can use your admin access to update the module (unless you need to change something that's not configurable in the module).

Comment: I found the index.ascx where you said it would be. Only problem is that the first line of index.ascx becomes the 10th line on the fully rendered webpage. The file indicates no 'include function' directing me to where I can find the <head></head>

Comment: Though finding the index.ascx is a huge help because now I can actually edit the rest of the skin, but the <head></head> still remains out of reach.

Comment: As Mitchel said, you access that through the page settings.  Through the website, click on the Settings link from the Pages menu (assuming DNN 6; otherwise look for Page Settings in the control panel somewhere).  In the page settings, there's a "Page Header Tags" field, which will be injected directly in the `<head>` tag.

Comment: This answer ignores the question's key requirement that content be injected into the <head> element of the page, not something easily done by editing the skin or a module in the "header" pane (not the same as the <head> element at all)